# Adding but not Overwriting Text

Tags: javascript

I have a function called "StartMsg"
that I want to add text to a div element with the id "Screen". But sadly I known only basic JS, here is what I have so far;

```
function StartMsg() {   
document.getElementById('Screen').innerHTML = "The            game was created.";
}
```

But it overwrites all of my previous text (Yes I know it's supposed to do that, I'm trying to find a way to not overwrite but add!).

Comment: `document.getElementById('Screen').innerHTML += "The            game was created.";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textContent` and con-cat the new string

```
document.getElementById('Screen').textContent += " The game was created.";
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dr4mznkr/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `createTextNode()` method,

```
var your_div = document.getElementById('Screen');
var your_text = document.createTextNode("text added");
your_div.appendChild(your_content);
```

Using `innerHTML` will remove all listeners within the `div` element

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the `append` method.

For example:

```
$('variable').append('some text');
```